# Retrieving Attachment Display Settings Utilizing WordPress Media Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, ckeditor

I'm having some trouble finding answer as WordPress media javascript seems to be poorly documented.

I am working on a project that needs to replace the default TinyMCE editor with CKEditor.

I have the following code to open up the media manager:

```
frame = new wp.media.view.MediaFrame.Post({
    title: "Media Manager",
    library: {
        ...
        type: 'image',
        ...
    },
    button: {
        text: "Insert Images"
    },
    multiple: true,
    state: 'insert'
});
```

And to insert images, the following:

```
frame.on('insert', function (){
    var html = [];
    var attachments = frame.state().get('selection');
    var selected = attachments.models;

    selected.forEach(function (selection){
        var attachment = selection.toJSON();

        html.push(
            "<figure class='image'>" +
            "<img src='" + attachment.url + "' alt='" + attachment.alt + "'/>" +
            (attachment.caption !== '' ? "<figcaption>" + attachment.caption + "</figcaption>" : "") +
            "</figure>"
        );
    });

    editor.insertHtml(html.toString());
});
```

Which works great to insert any number of images into the CKEditor.

However, rather than using the full sized image, I would like to use the image URL for whatever sized image was selected in the "Size" field under "Attachment Display Settings" (see image). I'm sure there is a way to access the data in those "Attachment Display Settings" fields, however I cannot seem to find any information about this anywhere.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this ?

Comment: @Norman, not yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same probleme like you and I can´t get the data from the Attachment Display Settings. But if you want the url of an medium size image you can also use this:

```
attachment.sizes.medium.url;
```

[Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/151693) you can finde more about this and at the bottom there is a way to use the Attachment Display Settings, but I couldn´t figure it out yet how to use it.